# Scrape links from website without duplicates

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape all links from a website with the text on each site.
Right now my code is creating duplicates, a lot of them, which i would like to avoid.
Could you please help and tell me where is my mistake?

Here is my spider

```
class SuperSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    base_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/'),
                  callback='parse', follow=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        url_list = []
        for quote in response.css('div'):
            name =  quote.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            if name in url_list:
                continue
            url_list.append(name)
            yield {
                'Link_without_base_url': quote.xpath('.//a/@href').get(),
                'Text':  response.css("::text").extract(),
            }
```

and example of json I'm getting

```
{"Link_without_base_url": "/", "Text": ["\n", "\n\t", "\n\t", "Quotes to Scrape", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n", "\n", "\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            ", "\n                ", "\n                    ", "Quotes to Scrape", "\n                ", "\n            ", "\n            ", "\n                ", "\n                \n                    ", "Login", "\n                \n                ", "\n            ", "\n        ", "\n    \n\n", "Viewing tag: ", "better-life-empathy", "\n\n", "\n    ", "\n\n    ", "\n        ", "\u201cYou never really understand a person until you consider things from his point of view... Until you climb inside of his skin and walk around in it.\u201d", "\n        ", "by ", "Harper Lee", "\n        ", "(about)", "\n        ", "\n        ", "\n            Tags:\n            ", " \n            \n            ", "better-life-empathy", "\n            \n        ", "\n    ", "\n\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            \n            \n        ", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n        \n            ", "Top Ten tags", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "love", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "inspirational", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "life", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "humor", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "books", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "reading", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "friendship", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "friends", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "truth", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "simile", "\n            ", "\n            \n        \n    ", "\n", "\n\n    ", "\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            ", "\n                Quotes by: ", "GoodReads.com", "\n            ", "\n            ", "\n                Made with ", "\u2764", " by ", "Scrapinghub", "\n            ", "\n        ", "\n    ", "\n", "\n"]},
{"Link_without_base_url": "/", "Text": ["\n", "\n\t", "\n\t", "Quotes to Scrape", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n", "\n", "\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            ", "\n                ", "\n                    ", "Quotes to Scrape", "\n                ", "\n            ", "\n            ", "\n                ", "\n                \n                    ", "Login", "\n                \n                ", "\n            ", "\n        ", "\n    \n\n", "Viewing tag: ", "better-life-empathy", "\n\n", "\n    ", "\n\n    ", "\n        ", "\u201cYou never really understand a person until you consider things from his point of view... Until you climb inside of his skin and walk around in it.\u201d", "\n        ", "by ", "Harper Lee", "\n        ", "(about)", "\n        ", "\n        ", "\n            Tags:\n            ", " \n            \n            ", "better-life-empathy", "\n            \n        ", "\n    ", "\n\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            \n            \n        ", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n        \n            ", "Top Ten tags", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "love", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "inspirational", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "life", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "humor", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "books", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "reading", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "friendship", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "friends", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "truth", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "simile", "\n            ", "\n            \n        \n    ", "\n", "\n\n    ", "\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            ", "\n                Quotes by: ", "GoodReads.com", "\n            ", "\n            ", "\n                Made with ", "\u2764", " by ", "Scrapinghub", "\n            ", "\n        ", "\n    ", "\n", "\n"]},
{"Link_without_base_url": "/", "Text": ["\n", "\n\t", "\n\t", "Quotes to Scrape", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n", "\n", "\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            ", "\n                ", "\n                    ", "Quotes to Scrape", "\n                ", "\n            ", "\n            ", "\n                ", "\n                \n                    ", "Login", "\n                \n                ", "\n            ", "\n        ", "\n    \n\n", "Viewing tag: ", "better-life-empathy", "\n\n", "\n    ", "\n\n    ", "\n        ", "\u201cYou never really understand a person until you consider things from his point of view... Until you climb inside of his skin and walk around in it.\u201d", "\n        ", "by ", "Harper Lee", "\n        ", "(about)", "\n        ", "\n        ", "\n            Tags:\n            ", " \n            \n            ", "better-life-empathy", "\n            \n        ", "\n    ", "\n\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            \n            \n        ", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n    ", "\n        \n            ", "Top Ten tags", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "love", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "inspirational", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "life", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "humor", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "books", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "reading", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "friendship", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "friends", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "truth", "\n            ", "\n            \n            ", "\n            ", "simile", "\n            ", "\n            \n        \n    ", "\n", "\n\n    ", "\n    ", "\n        ", "\n            ", "\n                Quotes by: ", "GoodReads.com", "\n            ", "\n            ", "\n                Made with ", "\u2764", " by ", "Scrapinghub", "\n            ", "\n        ", "\n    ", "\n", "\n"]},
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, You can select all list items and iterate then select link and text item as follows:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]'):

            yield {
                'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com' + quote.css('.text~span a::attr(href)').get(),
                'Text': quote.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').get()
            }

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess(QuotesSpider)
    process.crawl()
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without 
changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without 
changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without 
changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without 
changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt', 'Text': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2022-06-21 01:28:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'Link_without_base_url': 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'Text': '“The 
world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.
What about more universal approach?
I'm trying to create such map for any website

Comment: @mmalagocki Thanks, more universal approach is  you can call another def(self, response) and invoke each link with callback then you will visit the each individual page and from here you can grab all of the desired data easily,

Comment: Sorry, but i can't figure it out on my own. I should still rely on 'xpath', right?

Comment: Hi @mmalagocki, if you're satisfied with F.Hoque's answer, then please consider accepting it.